# Migrating Qt project file to CMake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5

I'm trying to migrate a QtProject file, exactly the QtAwesome library from https://github.com/gamecreature/QtAwesome

The project file that im trying to migrate is:

```
TARGET = QtAwesome
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib c++11

SOURCES += QtAwesome.cpp
HEADERS += QtAwesome.h

isEmpty(PREFIX) {
    unix {
        PREFIX = /usr
    } else {
        PREFIX = $$[QT_INSTALL_PREFIX]
    }
}

install_headers.files = QtAwesome.h
install_headers.path = $$PREFIX/include
target.path = $$PREFIX/lib
INSTALLS += install_headers target

RESOURCES += \
    QtAwesome.qrc
```

And my translation is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(QtAwesome)
file(GLOB_RECURSE CODE_FILES QtAwesome.cpp)
find_package (Qt5Core REQUIRED)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DQTAWESOME_LIBRARY)

qt5_add_resources(RESOURCE_FILES QtAwesome.qrc)
qt5_wrap_cpp(LIB_HEADER_MOC QtAwesome.h)

add_library(QtAwesome STATIC QtAwesome.cpp QtAwesome.h)
target_link_libraries(QtAwesome
    Qt5::Widgets
)
```

It compiles, but when i try to use this built library i get the following error:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable MyProject.exe
QtAwesome.lib(QtAwesome.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl qInitResources_QtAwesome(void)" (?qInitResources_QtAwesome@@YAHXZ) referenced in function "public: bool __cdecl QtAwesome::initFontAwesome(void)" (?initFontAwesome@QtAwesome@@QEAA_NXZ)

MyProject.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Comment: Where is LIB_SOURCE being set?

Comment: @mascoj I've just updated the cmake file without LIB_SOURCE and setting my source, and I'm still having issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues in your cmake project:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE CODE_FILES QtAwesome.cpp)
```

You're not using `CODE_FILES` anywhere. Moreover, using glob with a file name instead of a file pattern is non-sense, and glob should not be used to collect sources (see the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/file.html)).

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DQTAWESOME_LIBRARY)
```

`QTAWESOME_LIBRARY` is not used anywhere in QtAwesome's code (see [search result in the repository](https://github.com/gamecreature/QtAwesome/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=QTAWESOME_LIBRARY)). Anyway, if you must add defintions, you may consider [`target_compile_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/target_compile_definitions.html) instead.

```
qt5_add_resources(RESOURCE_FILES QtAwesome.qrc)
qt5_wrap_cpp(LIB_HEADER_MOC QtAwesome.h)
```

`RESOURCE_FILES` and `LIB_HEADER_MOC` are not added to the sources when calling `add_library`: resources and moc files will not be compiled into your library (I guess that is your main issue here). You may consider using `CMAKE_AUTOMOC`and `CMAKE_AUTORCC` instead.

```
find_package (Qt5Core REQUIRED)

# ...

target_link_libraries(QtAwesome
    Qt5::Widgets
)
```

You're linking against the `Widgets` module while only looking for the `Core` module.

You didn't require C++11 standard in your cmake project: you may require it using [`CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html), or, if you know which part of the standard is required, using [compile features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220265/check-if-a-c11-feature-is-enabled-in-compiler-with-cmake/41221098#41221098).

Once cleaned, your cmake project may look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(QtAwesome)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)

add_library(QtAwesome STATIC
    QtAwesome.cpp
    QtAwesome.h
    QtAwesome.qrc
)
target_link_libraries(QtAwesome
    Qt5::Widgets
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this very helpful
https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/util/cmake/run_pro2cmake.py

I was able to convert a qmake (.pro) project to cmake.  It generated a working CMakeLists.txt