# check if a c++11 feature is enabled in compiler with CMAKE

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake

I'm developing a project with CMake. My code contains `constexpr` methods, that are allowed in Visual Studio 2015, but not in Visual Studio 2013.

How can I check in the `CMakeLists.txt` if the feature is supported by the specified compiler? I've seen in CMake documentation [`CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES.html), but I didn't understand how to use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [target_compile_features](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_features.html) to require a C++11(/14/17) feature:

```
target_compile_features(target PRIVATE|PUBLIC|INTERFACE feature1 [feature2 ...])
```

With `feature1` being a feature listed in [`CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES.html). For example, if you want to use `constexpr` in your public API, you can use:

```
add_library(foo ...)
target_compile_features(foo PUBLIC cxx_constexpr)
```

---

You should also take a look at the [`WriteCompilerDetectionHeader` module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/WriteCompilerDetectionHeader.html) which allows to detect features as options, and provides a backward compatibility implementation for some features if the compiler does not support them:

```
write_compiler_detection_header(
    FILE foo_compiler_detection.h
    PREFIX FOO
    COMPILERS GNU MSVC
    FEATURES cxx_constexpr cxx_nullptr
)
```

Here a file `foo_compiler_detection.h` will be generated with `FOO_COMPILER_CXX_CONSTEXPR` defined if the keyword `constexpr` is available:

```
#include "foo_compiler_detection.h"

#if FOO_COMPILER_CXX_CONSTEXPR

// implementation with constexpr available
constexpr int bar = 0;

#else

// implementation with constexpr not available
const int bar = 0;

#endif
```

Moreover, `FOO_CONSTEXPR` will be defined and will expand to `constexpr` if the feature exists for the current compiler. It will be empty otherwise.

`FOO_NULLPTR` will be defined and will expand to `nullptr` if the feature exists for the current compiler. It will expand to a compatibility implementation otherwise (e.g. `NULL`).

```
#include "foo_compiler_detection.h"

FOO_CONSTEXPR int bar = 0;

void baz(int* p = FOO_NULLPTR);
```

See [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html).