# How to compile with different compile options for different files in CMAKE?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, clang, rtti

I have a project like this:

```
|--CMakeLists.txt(1)
|--File1.cpp -W -W-all
|--Folder1
    |--CMakeLists.txt(2)
    |--File2.cpp -W -W-all -fno-rtti
```

As you can see above, `File2.cpp` needs to compile with `-fno-rtti` whereas the other files should compile with `rtti`. This is happening because I'm using both clang and boost libraries in my project.
I wrote `CMakeLists.txt(1)` like this:

```
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -fexceptions -fno-rtti -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -Wno-long-long" )
```

And, in `CMakeLists.txt(2)` I added the following:

```
add_definitions( -fno-rtti )
```

The above did not work. In fact none of the following have worked for me in CMakeLists.txt(2)

```
set_property(SOURCE File2.cpp APPEND_STRING PROPERTY CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -fno-rtti ")
set_property(SOURCE File2.cpp APPEND_STRING PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS " -fno-rtti ")
ADD_DEFINITIONS(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -fno-rtti ")
ADD_DEFINITIONS(COMPILE_FLAGS " -fno-rtti ")
ADD_DEFINITIONS( -fno-rtti )
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: How do you know it didn't work? What errors do you get? Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670121/using-cmake-with-gnu-make-how-can-i-see-the-exact-commands)?

Comment: Duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638408/override-compile-flags-for-single-files)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AFAIK CMake does not allow to specify compile options per file. The best you can do is to create a target for the files you want to compile with `-fno-rtti`, e.g. with `add_library`, and add the compile options to this target.

[`add_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions.html) is meant to add preprocessor definitions. You should consider [`add_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html) instead:

```
add_compile_options(-fno-rtti)
```

To avoid global pollution and make sure you add your options **only** to a given target, you may consider using [`target_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html):

```
target_compile_options(foo PUBLIC -fno-rtti)
```

---

Unrelated, but instead of manually setting flags to enable c++11 with `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 ...")`, let cmake do a more fine grained job with [compile features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220265/check-if-a-c11-feature-is-enabled-in-compiler-with-cmake/41221098#41221098), or at least with standard selection:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Looking more carefully in the documentation, you can set compile flags per source file using [set_source_files_properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_source_files_properties.html) with [COMPILE_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/COMPILE_FLAGS.html):

```
set_source_files_properties(File2.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -fno-rtti)
```

Comment: To avoid global pollution wouldn't it be better to use `PRIVATE` instead of `PUBLIC` target compile options?

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, but the fix was actually in the CmakeLists.txt(2). I was not building (by calling add_library) for that individual file. Once I added the add_library, and linked it at top level , it was OK. Not sure if there is a way to workaround (must be) without creating a lib out of this one file. For ex. in XCODE we can specify directly which files need to compile with which options and generates a single executable. Does Cmake allow that ? If yes, what should I add in CMakeLists.txt(2) ?

Comment: @UtkarshKumar I reread your question and the documention, `set_source_files_properties` should work for you. In your question, you used it on `File1.cpp` instead of `File2.cpp`: is that a typo?

Comment: Thanks for correcting. I haven't tried set_source_files_properties, I think I only tried set_property. Would verify against this command and update.

Comment: It looks like [`COMPILE_FLAGS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/prop_sf/COMPILE_FLAGS.html#prop_sf:COMPILE_FLAGS) is now deprecated, and `COMPILE_OPTIONS` should be used instead.