# add flags using cmake

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, preprocessor

I created a static library with cmake. I have a library.h, library.cpp and main.cpp.
all my functions declared in library.h and implemented in library.cpp. I make the project using default make file (make all).
now I declare some macro (e.g. #ifndef MEM ... #else ...). if macro used, the flags: -DMEM -DPREP=20 -DM=1200 should be added.I added following to my make file:

```
swtest: CPPFLAGS += -DM=1200 -DMEM -DPREP=20 -g
```

and then I make project using:

```
make swtest
```

and then compile main.cpp with:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main lib.a -DMEM -DPREP=20 -DM=1200 -g
```

but it does not work.
I think I should add some code to my cmakelists file but I don't know how!
I emphasize that my macros added to library.cpp not main.cpp.
note that I'm using clion.

Comment: Why do you show snippets from a makefile, but claim to be using CMake?

Comment: If you want to use different compiler flags for different source files, then use `set_source_files_properties` command as described in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635314/how-to-compile-with-different-compile-options-for-different-files-in-cmake).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you specify the defines when compiling library.cpp.

Comment: If I knew how to do this, I would not ask question anymore!!